# Tribe of Asher found in Luke 2

Tags: chronology

In Luke 2:36 he mentions Anna of the Tribe of Asher. How long has it been since this tribe has been mentioned in scripture?

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your contribution.  Please remember to take the tour (link blow left) to better understand how this site works.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of the date of writing, 2 Chronicles would be the most recent. Since it mentions the decree of Cyrus allowing the Jews to return to Jerusalem, it was certainly written after the Exile, and some scholars place it as late as circa the 3rd c. B.C.E. However, the reference is to an earlier time, during the reign of King Hezekiah.

2 Chronicles 30:10, 11

> <sup>**10**</sup> So the couriers passed from city to city in the land of Ephraim and Manasseh and as far as Zebulun, but they were derided and scoffed at. <sup>**11**</sup> Nevertheless, some from Asher, Manasseh, and Zebulun humbled themselves and came to Jerusalem.

Ezekiel, who wrote during the Exile, also mentions Asher (Ezek. 48) but speaks of its territory rather than the tribe itself. Asher is normally considered a "lost" tribe but it seems that many Jews maintained an affiliation with their tribal ancestry, even though the tribe's political structure no longer functioned.